# Can't write to file from child process

Tags: python

I can't wrap my head around this... I have the following code:

```
def launch(command):
    pf = os.path.join(working_directory, '.pid')

    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        stdout = os.open(..., os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT)
        try:
            proc = Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=stdout, cwd=workdir)
            print(proc.pid)
            with open(pf, 'wb') as p: # pf should not be open as the file is just created.
                p.write(proc.pid)
            print("Hello World")
        except OSError as proc_error:
            ...
        finally:
            os._exit(o) # socketserver catches SystemExit exception (flask)
    else:
        start = time.time()
        while not os.path.isfile(pf): # I'm just checking if that file exists here never opened it in the first place.
            if time.time() - start >= 30:
                 raise TimeoutError...
            time.sleep(5)

        pid = int(open(pf, 'rb').read())
```

Here's the output:

- $pid
- TimeoutError occurred

The script seem to be hanging at opening pf for writing. I verified, the file if not created, Hello World never gets printed.

Why is this happening, and how can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to always include code that can be copy pasted by others to easily reproduce your error. Read up on [how to create a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is the most complete code sample I can give. The problem is that the open call fails and the whole child process hangs. If I go with debugger and reach the with open line, whatever I try, Step into Step over the debugger stops the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reduced your code to this (removing everything I could not reproduce given your code):

```
import os
import time
s = "foo"
pid = os.fork()
from subprocess import Popen

if pid == 0:
    proc = Popen(["sleep", "3"])
    with open(s, "w") as p:
        p.write(str(proc.pid)) # <- Only real error I could see
    os._exit(0)

else:
    start = time.time()
    while not os.path.isfile(s):
        if time.time() - start >= 30:
            raise TimeoutError("Command took to long")
        time.sleep(5)

    print("Read from file: " + open(s, 'r').read())
```

However, it works just fine, it prints `Read from file: 12075`. So the issue is not in the part that can be reproduced, given your code.

To read/write the procid to the binary file I succesfully used the pickle module:

```
pickle.dump(proc.pid,p) # write to file
pickle.load(open(s, "rb")) #read from file
```

Comment: if I write p.write(str(proc.pid)) the pid is written to the file. However, opening it in 'wb' mode and writting it as p.write(proc.pid) nothing is written. Btw my python version is 3.4.4

Comment: Ah okay, I tested it using 3.6, maybe there is a difference, let me check

Comment: I get an error when I open as binary and then try to write the int. Might need to use pickle.dump() to write the int to the file

Comment: Alright, so the solution was: p.write(struct.pack('I', proc.pid))
then in the read you use unpack.